# Web Scraping - Curl Command Different From Browser Output?

Tags: javascript, json, linux, curl, http-headers

When I paste [this link](https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/@tiktok/7156280167344688426) into my browser, I see a bunch of JSON. I would like to see this same JSON using the `curl` command. However, running `curl https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/@tiktok/7156280167344688426` returns the following JSON:

```
{
    statusCode: 0,
    body: {
        statusCode: -1,
        videoData: {},
        shareUser: {}
    }
}
```

This isn't what I see in my browser. Even when I try to set the headers to Chrome or Firefox, I get the same results, so I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My apologies if this is a silly question; I don't know much about the specifics of how a browser works. Feel free to recommend sources for further learning if you have them.

Comment: I think it happens because of cookies, authentication heardes, etc. On your browser, you are logged in, am I right?

Comment: No - I'm using a fresh incognito browser, with no login.